# Detecting if two divs are too close or collide/overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlap

I'm trying to detect if two given `div`'s are too close or collide/overlap .

I have the below codepen which tries to generate 20 random `div`'s and only append them to body if their position isn't too close to other existing `div`.

That's the idea but it doesn't work as expected where i get `div`'s that get through with close/overlapping positions to existing `div`s. (run it multiple times if first time is perfect and you should come across it).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fHLzj

Can anyone see the mistake and way to make it work?

Comment: Hey @op it seems you are learning the way i learned... i did this in march 2013 http://www.lastnoob.com/ check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat hard to explain and get..but here goes:

**check every div against every div** by running for loop.

x,y,h,w

- x is top-left corner's distance from left.
- y is top-left corner's distance from top.
- h is div's height.
- w is div's width.

Point to consider... you don't really need to check every div..consider this

there are 10 divs...

- First you will check 1st against 9.
- Second one against 8.
- .............
- Eight one against 2.
- Ninth one against 1.
- And don't the last one.

Also it's a good idea to assign values and check for collisions in data, before assigning them  to dom. Dom should be just for rendering final result.

I'll assume you want to keep none of the two colliding divs.

**Preview**
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/m4fSf/6/

as expected code is huge

```
var
div={},
number=10,
size=20,
m = ele('main');
mw= parseFloat(getComputedStyle(m).getPropertyValue("width"))-size,
mh= parseFloat(getComputedStyle(m).getPropertyValue("height"))-size,
f=true,
nn;    

var i
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    div[i] = {};
    var t = true, newX, newY, nn;
   if (i!=0){ 
       while (t) {

        newX = rand(mw);
        newY = rand(mh);

        for (nn = 0; nn < i; nn++) {
            if (!(((newX > div[nn].x + size+5) || (newY > div[nn].y + size+5)) ||
             ((newX + size+5 < div[nn].x) || (newY + size+5 < div[nn].y)))) {
                    break;
                }
                if (nn == i-1) t = false;
            }}} else {
        newX = rand(mw);
        newY = rand(mh);
            }


console.log(newX);
    div[i].x = newX;
    div[i].y = newY;
}

for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
render(div[i]);
}


console.log(div);
function render(x){
var d=document.createElement('div');
    d.style.position='absolute';
    d.style.left=(x.x+'px');
    d.style.top=(x.y+'px');
    m.appendChild(d);
}
function rand(x) { return Math.random()*x;} 
function ele(x){return document.getElementById(x);}
```

this code is from my collision site...ill try and put it in the code above, but this what's needed to avoid collisions and close gaps.

```
if (xpost+30>xx.left && xx.left>xpost && xx.top+30>ypost  && xx.top<ypost+30)  { xspeed = -speed; }
            if (xpost<xx.left+30 && xx.left<xpost && xx.top+30>ypost  && xx.top<ypost+30)  { xspeed = speed; }
            if (ypost+30>xx.top && xx.top>ypost && xx.left+30>xpost  && xx.left<xpost+30)  { yspeed = -speed; }
            if (ypost<xx.top+30 && xx.top<ypost && xx.left+30>xpost  && xx.left<xpost+30)  { yspeed = speed; }
```

Comment: when you check 9th div for collision you don't check it against previous divs. Because if they are not colliding with it, so this is not colliding with anyone else. But it could be colliding with the next one, and when its not. Then it means last one isn't colliding with anyone else either.

Comment: @Muhammad Umer Can you also please post the demo on codepen.io . jsFiddle is blocked me for here.

Comment: @Muhammad Umer you code avoid collision only right? and it doesn't care if the gap (top/left) is sufficient between the position of the current div compared to neighbouring DIV before rendering the div. or am i reading the code wrong?

Comment: yes but to do that all you need to do is add a number after all `+ size` in that big if statement like this..`div[nn].x + size+5`

Comment: and yes it's not complete for that, need to change that if statement more.

Comment: @Muhammad Umer your code ends up in an endless loop trying to fix the DIVs if the width/height of `main` is small and the number of the divs is high. what would you suggest for such scenario?

Comment: i tried it's not endless...usually it gets it in either 2 to 8 tries.

Comment: btw it's amazing that you can understand it without comments and stuff. I suck completely at reading other's code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the collision logic. It detects if an object is close to another object by comparing the distance between the objects. I wrapped the logic in a do-while loop as well, so that it will keep attempting to find a position to place the square and you'll have exactly 20 squares.

This works:

```
var positions = [];  //stroe positions of appended divs
var divsize = 20; 
var topGap = 40;  // gap from top
var leftGap = 80;  //gap from left

function generateRandomPositionedDiv(){
    for(var c = 0; c < 20; c++){
        var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);

            $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
                'width':divsize+'px',
                'height':divsize+'px',
                'background-color': color
            }); 



                var posLeft;
                var posTop;
                var checkObj;
                var collide = false;

                posLeft = Math.floor((Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)));//.toFixed();
                posTop = Math.floor((Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)));//.toFixed();
                checkObj = {x: posLeft, y: posTop};

                collide = checkForCollisions(checkObj);

            if(!collide) {

                positions.push({x: posLeft, y: posTop});

                $newdiv.css({
                    'position':'absolute',
                    'left':posLeft+'px',
                    'top':posTop+'px'
                });

                $('body').append($newdiv);
            }

    }
}

/*function getPositions(box) {
  var $box = $(box);
  var pos = $box.position();
  var width = $box.width();
  var height = $box.height();
  return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width + leftGap ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height + topGap ] ];
}*/


function comparePositions(obj1, obj2) { 
    if(Math.abs(obj1.x - obj2.x) <= (divsize + leftGap) && Math.abs(obj1.y - obj2.y) <= (divsize + topGap)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function checkForCollisions(posObj){
    for(var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
        var match = comparePositions(positions[i], posObj);
        if (match) { 
                //return true if two positions are close or overlapping
                return match;
            }
    }
}

generateRandomPositionedDiv();
```

Comment: #CodePupper Your code doesn't seem like it takes into account LEFT or TOP gap between two DIVs (`var topGap = 40;  
var leftGap = 80; `) . Can you make it so that it places div's only if they're correctly apart from the existing positions based on top and  left?

Comment: I'm guessing what you mean by this is that no two squares can be within 80 pixels of each other on the x-axis and 40 pixels on the y-axis. I've edited my code to reflect that change. Let me know if that works :)

Comment: i tried your code - it freezes on second/third run. I'm guessing it gets in a endless loop in trying to find a suitable gap forever!

Comment: You're right, the code could go into an infinite loop. I've updated the code so that it does 20 attempts rather than trying to place exactly 20 squares.

Answer (score 0):

How about using one of these libraries to detect the collisions for you?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

http://gamequeryjs.com/

Comment: the second link seems a bit of an overkill. I didn't think it would be difficult to implement so didn't consider using external libraries. For sake of learning and to keep the question in focus i prefer not having to use an external library. Note that i have two things in mind , its not just Collision Detection but also GAP between two given DIVs, i.e. They can't overlap and they cannot be closer than specific TOP and LEFT to their neighbouring DIVs.

Comment: jquerycollision can also tell you the gap between 2 elements as well as whether it collides, having said that it sounds like you might want to solve an optimisation problem, the best way to lay something out given constraints. They are best solved using some kind of AI like genetic algorithms. Check the little demo program at the end http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat3.html